# Сокращение js скриптов

Tags: javascript

На сайте к странице подключается около 15 js скриптов и 10 css файлов, будет ли профит если свести весь js и css в один файл, т.е. просто все объединить? Сильно ли это ускорит загрузку сайта?

Comment: да, и лучше сделать это с помощью webpack

Comment: Не знаю чем лучше будет, если сделать это "с помощью webpack", а не любым другим способом, но объединение в век HTTP/1.1 явно не помешает.

Comment: Будет или нет — станет ясно только если попробовать на практике

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для HTTP/1.1 слияние css и js файлов уменьшает количество HTTP-запросов и тем самым влияет на время загрузки страницы (а также на индексацию и ранжирование страниц сайта в поисковых системах).

Для HTTP/2.0 это не критично, т.к. проблема загрузки множества скриптов и стилей решается мультиплексирующим соединением от клиента к хосту.

В целях экономии ресурсов сервера можно также сжимать CSS и JS файлы. Это уж точно даст выигрыш для HTTP/1.1 и HTTP/2.0.

Comment: А как можно проверить какая версия http используется на каком-либо сайте?

Comment: Проверка, поддерживает ли ваш сервер или CDN технологию HTTP/2:
https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test

Comment: Вот ещё пара статей

Comment: "Как я пытался включить http2 у себя на проекте с nginx": https://habrahabr.ru/post/314474/ и "Включаем HTTP/2 в NGINX для сайта": https://habrahabr.ru/company/infobox/blog/268599/